# Deploy a proyect with Gitlab cd/ci and lftp in a server with cpanels

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline, lftp

I has been reainding some question and articles before make this question:

- [gitlab ci pipeline failed deploy ftp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60476838/gitlab-ci-pipeline-failed-deploy-ftp)
- [Use GitLab CI to deploy app with ftp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42121021/use-gitlab-ci-to-deploy-app-with-ftp)
- [LFTP in gitlab CI: files are not updated on FTP server even if they are changed in the last commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55246916/lftp-in-gitlab-ci-files-are-not-updated-on-ftp-server-even-if-they-are-changed)
- [Use Gitlab Pipeline to push data to ftpserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49632077/use-gitlab-pipeline-to-push-data-to-ftpserver)
- https://savjee.be/2019/04/gitlab-ci-deploy-to-ftp-with-lftp/

My problem is that I use the pipeline variables I can not login.

```
$ lftp -e "set ssl:verify-certificate false; mirror --reverse --verbose=3 --delete ./ ./ --ignore-time --parallel=10 --exclude-glob .git* --exclude .git/; quit" -u $FTP_USER,$FTP_PASS $FTP_HOST
mirror: Login failed: 530 Login authentication failed
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
```

But if I add the varaible value in the yml it works. Cpanels fpt user is build in this way: `user@domian` I don't know if this can be the problem when it's in a variable.

```
$ lftp -e "set ssl:verify-certificate false; mirror --reverse --verbose=3 --delete ./ ./ --ignore-time --parallel=10 --exclude-glob .git* --exclude .git/; quit" -u user@domian,password domain
```

Comment: Did u echo the variable values and check the values and order.

Comment: Thanks @Origin , I had written variable's name wrong, I had "FPT_PASS" instead of "FTP_PASS"

Comment: Happy to help :). I have added an answer. If it was usefull to you please consider accepting it so it can help others as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In such cases where you are able to successfully run the command directly but it's not working when using variables. Checking a few cases usually helps.

1. Echo the variable and check the values and order
2. Check if the variable is protected. Protected variables are only accessible in protected branches.